# Finding files with both of two specified terms via git grep

Tags: python, git, unix, grep, git-grep

I'm attempting to find files in my git repository using git grep and I have no easy way of doing so without manual searching. I have found one workaround like this:

```
git grep -l 'term1' | xargs -i grep -l term2 {}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way similar to this which doesn't require xargs:

```
git grep -l -E 'term1|term2'
```

This essentially means show me the files containing either term1 or terms2... is there a "show me files with BOTH these terms."

I'm trying to use the git grep command in a way that is not practical for piping commands into other commands. I really hate working with python's subprocess module and its use of piping...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to achieve the goal:

***1)*** combining multiple patterns specified by `-e` option with `--and` flag

> **--and**
>   **--or**
>   **--not**
>  
>   **( …​ )** 
>   Specify how multiple patterns are combined using Boolean expressions.

```
git grep -l -e 'term1' --and -e 'term2'
```

---

***2)*** using `--all-match` flag

> When giving multiple pattern expressions combined with *--or*, this flag
>   is specified to limit the match to files that have lines to match all
>   of them.

```
git grep -l --all-match -e 'term1' -e 'term2'
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#git-grep--e

Comment: These options are producing different results for me. Option number 1 appears to require term1 and term2 be on the same line within the file, whereas option number 2 just requires both terms in the same file. I think the latter is more along the lines of what OP was asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine it with another grep command:

```
git grep -l -E 'term1' | grep term2
```